# HOW TO IMPORT AED , CANADA , GERMANY, FRANCE, JAPAN, SINGAPORE, CHINA CURRENCY IN MAGNETO2.2

Tags: magento2, currency

> AFTER SELECT AED CURRENCY IN UAE STORE.
>   FRONTEND SHOWING ONLY USD CURRENCY.
>   HOW I SHOW AED CURRENCY IN UAE STORE ON FRONTEND? 
>   ALSO OTHER DIFFRENT-2 CURRENCIES FOR DIFFERENT-2 STORE VIEWS?

[image]

Answer (score 0):

You have need to update currency rates. login admin and

Go to Stores > Currency Rates

I am in version 2.2.5 and at the moment Webservices imports are not working, some endpoints are deprecated.

Manually update the quote value according to your primary currency and save.

```
bin/magento indexer:reindex 
bin/magento cache:flush
```

Comment: magento showing only 
AUD CAD EUR GBP SGD USD

Comment: how can i import currency of  Canada Germany France Australia UK Japan Singapore China

Comment: I'm not sure I understood your question well. I did a little testing by adding a store whose currency is AED and based on the dollar. At the moment the quotation is this: $ 1 dollar = 3.67 AED. I set these values in Currency Rates and in my frontend the correct value in the products is shown.

Comment: How to import AED currency in magento2?

Comment: At the moment for me none of the standard webservices arranged in Magento for stock quotes are working. Unless you install an extension or develop a new integration with quotation webservice, you will need to manually fill in the quotes value and save.

Comment: PLEASE SEE MY QUESTION EDITED TITLE

Comment: In Magento you need to have a main currency, in my case it is Dollar, you then arrow the value of your products, (in this case without changing stores scope) based on your default currency. After that, you can set a different currency for a specific store like in your print, then just follow what I wrote in my answer to get the values of the products in your currency in front. I filled in the quote values manually, because to me the imports of webservices are not working right now. Read more at: https://docs.magento.com/m2/ce/user_guide/stores/currency-overview.html

Answer (score 0):

Yeh!

> I found solution
>   Stores > Settings -> Configuration->Default Config->GENERAL->Currency Setup->Currency Options->Allowed Currencies
>   Select Currencies we want for our Multistores
>   After that go in Stores -> Currency -> Currency Rates and fill Currency Rates
>   After that go in Stores > Settings -> Configuration-> 
>   and Select Stores from dropdown list and Select Currency Store Wise From
>   GENERAL->Currency Setup->Currency Options->Allowed Currencies
>   Thanks